# jQuery UI autocomplete: dropdown disappears when Chrome loses focus

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-autocomplete

(Note I have not yet tested this in IE FF or Safari, I'm hoping there is some setting on the autocomplete to make this work...)

In Chrome, when I type some text into a box that triggers a jQuery UI autocomplete dropdown to appear, the dropdown disappears when I switch focus to another application (my programming app Visual Studio).

Is there a setting to make the autocomplete drop down menu "stick" and remain visible when the browser loses focus in the operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch to another application an `onblur` event will be fired by the browser which is what hides the autocomplete menu.  Your best bet to accomplish this "sticky" behavior is to attach an `onfocus` event handler to the `window` and open the autocomplete menu then.

```
$(function() {
    var autocomplete = $( 'whatever' ).autocomplete();

    $( window ).on( 'focus', function() {
        autocomplete.autocomplete( 'search' );
    });
});​
```

I have a live example of this here - http://jsfiddle.net/RmALY/1/show/.

Comment: So it is the window's blur event that hides the UL? Would be great if there was an option/setting to avoid this. I have some comboboxes that are based on the jqUI autocomplete widget, and they don't close during a window blur (but I open and close them programmatically, instead of letting the widget handle it, like I am for the elements this question is asked about). Maybe I'll dig into the jqUI source to find out more, thanks.